# set top of UIlabel as fraction of the screen size using storyboard

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, swift4

I want to position the top distance from my label as shown in the picture as a fraction from the screen size. The reason I want to do that is that If I use a different device the top distance is fixed. I don't want to do that. I want to say place the label at 40% percent of the screen height. How can I do that in storyboard using autolayout[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it in proportional to centerY

with centerY you have half screen so if you want it to be 0.4 of whole screen = 0.8 of half screen

[image]